# How many ways to choose subsets $A,B,C$ from set $\{1,..,n\}$ such that for $k≥1$ that divides $n$, for each $x∈A, kx∈B$

Tags: combinatorics

I know that $C$ is not dependent on $k$, so I have $2^n$ ways to choose $C$. I'm having trouble to find the number of ways to choose subsets $A$ and $B$ and finding the number of $k$'s that divide $n$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's not for every k that divides n, it is ∃k|n with 1≤k≤n ∀x∈A kx∈B

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following is what you are asking:

> How many choices of $A,B,C \subseteq \{ 1, \dots ,n \}$ are there such that they satisfy the following condition: $\forall k | n$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$ $\forall x \in A$ $kx \in B$.

This must hold, in particular, for $k=n$, and so $A$ cannot have any elements $x \geq 2$ as otherwise $nx > n$ so $nx \notin \{ 1, \dots ,n \} \supseteq B$. This means we can take $A = \emptyset$ with any choice of $B$  (as the condition is then vacuous), or $A = \{ 1 \}$ with any choice of $B$ that contains all divisors $1 \leq k \leq n$ of $n$.

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors $1 \leq k \leq n$ of $n$. In the case of $A = \{ 1 \}$, $B$ then has a choice of the remaining $n - d(n)$ elements (in addition to the $d(n)$ elements that it must have). This is therefore $2^{n - d(n)}$ such choices for $B$.

As you correctly say, in any case there are $2^{n}$ choices for $C$.

In total we have

$$(1 \times 2^n \times 2^n) + (1 \times 2^{n-d(n)} \times 2^n) = 2^{2n} (1 + 2^{-d(n)})$$

choices for the triple $(A,B,C)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I meant that there is a $k$ that divides $n$ and not for every $k$ that divides $n$. So, for example when $n=2$ by your answer I have 20 option to choose from, but, if the condition is $∃k|n$ so I'll have 36 options. Do you know what changes I need to do so that the equation will represent that?